# Determine SQL Server database select and insert/update frequency?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on optimising the indexes on a very large database. I need to know the frequency of insert/update statements compared to the frequency of selects. I'm wondering what is the best way to determine this.

Is it possible to do this by using the transaction-log? I'm looking for a method that is minimally invasive for the database performance.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) DMV.

`user_updates` column responds on your first question (insert/update statements):

> Number of updates by user queries. This includes Insert, Delete, and
>   Updates representing number of operations done not the actual rows
>   affected. For example, if you delete 1000 rows in one statement, this
>   count increments by 1

Other columns like

- `user_seeks` Number of seeks by user queries.
- `user_scans` Number of scans by user queries that did not use 'seek'
  predicate.
- `user_lookups` Number of bookmark lookups by user queries.

will help you to determine how useful was this index for user queries.

The only thing to remember here is that `DMV` holds the statistics only for the time db is `online`, I mean if you `restart` your server or simply put database `offline`/`restore` it the statistics are reset to 0.

---

> Is it possible to do this by using the transaction-log

`SELECT` statements are not logged.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!